# Cost function related question

Tags: cost-functions

**I am doing this practice problem for my exam:
The question says: an industry consists of a large number of firms, each of which has a cost function of the form: $c(w_1,w_2,q)=(q^2+1)w_1+(q^2+2)w_2$ with input prices $w_1$ and $w_2$ and output quantity $q$.**

**a) Find the average cost curve of a firm. Find the minimum of this cost function and describe how the quantity at the minimum point changes as the ratio of input prices $w_1/w_2$ changes.**

For this part of the question, what I did is: $AC=C/Q=(w_1+w_2)q+(w_1+2w_2)/q$, which is simple and next I am looking for the minimum which is calculated by $dAC/dq=w_1+w_2-(w_1+2w_2)/q^2=0$, and that leads to $q=\sqrt{(w_1+2w_2)/(w_1+w_2)}$. From this point, I become no clue what to do next.

**b) Find the short-run supply curve of an individual firm.**

For this part, I know that short-run supply curve is marginal cost curve which can be calculated by $dC/dQ=2q(w_1+w_2)$

**c) Find the long-run industry supply curve with $M$ firms. Under what conditions will firms enter or stay in the market?**

I have some clue how to do it, but not sure how I can find the curve with $M$ firms. On the other hand I do know when the firm enters or exit the market but I need to figure out the supply curve before I continue.

Thanks in advance!